# MongoDB findAndModify. Is it really atomic? Help writing a closed update solution

Tags: mongodb

I have `Event` documents, consisting of embedded `Snapshots`.

I want to add a `Snapshot` A to an `Event` if:

- That event started within 5 mins of snapshot A
- The latest snapshot on the Event is not greater than a minute before snapshot A.

Otherwise.... create a new `Event`.

Here is my `findAndUpdate` query that might make more sense:

```
Event.findAndModify(
  query: { 
    start_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 5min },
    last_snapshot_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 1min }
  },
  update: { 
    snapshots[newSnapshot.timestamp]: newSnapshot,
    $max: { last_snapshot_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp },
    $min: { start_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp }
  },
  upsert: true,
  $setOnInsert: { ALL OUR NEW EVENT FIELDS } }
)
```

Edit: Unfortunately, I cannot create a unique index on start_timestamp. Snapshots come in with different timestamps, and I want to group them into an event. I.e Snapshot A comes in at 12:00:00, and Snapshot B comes in at 12:00:59. They should be in the same event, but they could be written to the DB at different times, because the workers writing them are acting concurrently. Say another snapshot comes in, at 12:00:30, it should be written to the same event as the two above. Finally a snapshot at 12:02:00 should be written to a new event.

My question is.... will this work correctly in a concurrent environment. Is the `findAndUpdate` atomic? Is it possible I might create two events, when I should have created one, and added the snapshot to it?

**Edit: So the above approach is not guaranteed to not create two events, as @chainh kindly pointed out.**

**So I have tried a new locking based approach - do you think this would work?**

```
var acquireLock = function() {
  var query = { "locked": false}
  var update = { $set: { "locked": true } }
  return Lock.findAndModify({
    query: query, 
    update: update,
    upsert: true
  })
};

var releaseLock = function() {
  var query = { "locked": true }
  var update = { $set: { "locked": false } }
  return Lock.findAndModify({
    query: query, 
    update: update
  })
};

var insertSnapshot = function(newSnapshot, upsert) {
  Event.findAndModify(
    query: { 
      start_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 5min },
      last_snapshot_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 1min }
    },
    update: { 
      snapshots[newSnapshot.timestamp]: newSnapshot,
      $max: { last_snapshot_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp },
      $min: { start_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp }
    },
    upsert: upsert,
    $setOnInsert: { ALL OUR NEW EVENT FIELDS } }
  )
};

var safelyInsertEvent = function(snapshot) {
  return insertSnapshot(snapshot, false)
  .then(function(modifyRes) {
    if (!modifyRes.succeeded) {
      return acquireLock()
    }
  })
  .then(function(lockRes) {
    if (lockRes.succeeded) {
      return insertSnapshot(snapshot, true)
    } else {
      throw new AcquiringLockError("Didn't acquire lock. Try again")
    }
  })
  .then(function() {
    return releaseLock()
  })
  .catch(AcquiringLockError, function(err) {
    return safelyInsertEvent(snapshot)
  })
};
```

The lock document would simply contain a single field (locked). Basically the above code tries to find an existing event and update it. If it works, great, we can bail out. If we didn't update, we know we don't have an existing event to stick the snapshot in. So we then acquire a lock atomically, and if that succeeds, we can safely upsert a new event. If acquiring that lock fails, we simply try the whole process again, and hopefully by that time we have an existing event to stick it in.

Comment: I think if you create an unique index on **start_timestamp** of Event, then the first block of codes is able to avoid concurrent issue completely.

Comment: I cannot create a unique index because start_timestamp differs. I'll explain above.

Comment: By your query structure, I conceived that **Event** has a field **start_timestamp** that is created together with **Event** document, and no update after that moment. Is it correct? Could you place a full document of **Event** here to make more sense?

Comment: I can later (currently out). start_timestamp is mutated every time a snapshot timestamp < event's start_timestamp.

Comment: Is the lock implemented by MongoDB? If yes, you need to use a certain **_id** or unique index on **locked** field, else the lock will fail because upsert will always succeed; and this lock probably causes performance issue because it's a global lock, then only one upsert operation is allowed at the same time; and splitting modification and upsert operations explicitly will probably cause lower performance, comparing to simple findAndModify(if upsert fails , possibly to modify it without another request to database). Basically, it should work after clarify the lock issue, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your codes:

```
Event.findAndModify(
  query: { 
    start_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 5min },
    last_snapshot_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 1min }
  },
  update: { 
    snapshots[newSnapshot.timestamp]: newSnapshot,
    $max: { last_snapshot_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp },
    $min: { start_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp }
  },
  upsert: true,
  $setOnInsert: { ALL OUR NEW EVENT FIELDS } }
)
```

When succeed to insert the first Event document into database, fields of this Event document has following relationship:
start_timestamp == last_snapshot_timestamp

After subsequent updates, the relationship turns to:
start_timestamp < last_snapshot_timestamp < last_snapshot_timestamp + 1min < start_timestamp + 5min
OR
start_timestamp < last_snapshot_timestamp < start_timestamp + 5min < last_snapshot_timestamp + 1min

So, if new snapshot wants to insert into this Event document continuously, it must conform:
    newSnapshot.timestamp < Math.min(last_snapshot_timestamp + 1, start_timestamp + 5)

Suppose there are two Event documents in database over time:
Event1 (start_timestamp1, last_snapshot_timestamp1),
Event2 (start_timestamp2, last_snapshot_timestamp2)
Generally, start_timestamp2 > last_snapshot_timestamp1

Now, if there is a new snapshot comes, and its timestamp is less than start_timestamp1
(just suppose it's possible by latency or forging), then this snapshot can be inserted
into either Event document. So, I doubt whether you need another condition added into
the query part to make sure the distance between last_snapshot_timestamp and start_timestamp is always less than a certain value (e.g. 5min)? For example, I change the query to

```
  query: { 
        start_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 5min },
        last_snapshot_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - 1min , $lte : newSnapshot.timestamp + 5}
      }
```

Ok, let's continue...
If I try to solve this question, I still try to build a unique index on field **start_timestamp**. 
According to the manual of MongoDB, use **findAndModify** or **update** is able to finish the work 
atomically. But the headache is how should I handle when duplicate value occurs because 
newSnapshot.timestamp is out of control and it will possibly modify **start_timestamp** by 
operator **$min**.

The approaches are:

1. several threads create(upsert) a new Event document because no documents can satisfy the query condition;
2. one thread succeed to create the new Event document with certain newSnapshot.timestamp value, 
   others fail by the constraints of unique index on field **start_timestamp**;
3. other threads retry (now is update instead of upsert) and will succeed to update (use the existed Event document);
4. If an update(not upsert) causes to modify **start_timestamp** by **$min** operator and coincidentally newSnapshot.tiemstamp
   is equal to the value of **start_timestamp** in an existed Event document, the update will fail by constraints of unique
   index. But we can get the message, and we know an Event document has existed, whose **start_timestamp** value is just equal to
   newSnapshot.timestamp. Now, we can simply insert the newSnapshot into this Event document because it definitely conform the condition.

As it doesn't need to return Event document, I use **update** instead of **findAndModify** since both are atomic operation 
and **update** has simpler writing in this case.
I use simple JavaScript (run on mongo shell) to express steps (I'm not familiar with that code syntax you used. :D ), and I think you can understand easily.

```
var gap5 = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // just suppose, you should change accordingly if the value is not true. 
var gap1 = 1 * 60 * 1000;
var initialFields = {};     // ALL OUR NEW EVENT FIELDS

function insertSnapshotIfStartTimeStampNotExisted() {
    var query = { 
            start_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - gap5 },
            last_snapshot_timestamp: { $gte: newSnapshot.timestamp - gap1 }
    };
    var update = { 
            $push : {snapshots: newSnapshot}, // suppose snapshots is an array 
            $max: { last_snapshot_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp },
            $min: { start_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp },
            $setOnInsert : initialFields
    },

    var result = db.Event.update(query, update, {upsert : true});
    if (result.nUpserted == 0 && result.nModified == 0) {
        insertSnapshotIfStartTimeStampExisted();            // Event document existed with that start_timestamp
    }
}

function insertSnapshotIfStartTimeStampExisted() {
    var query = { 
            start_timestamp: newSnapshot.timestamp,
    };
    var update = { 
            $push : {snapshots: newSnapshot}
    },

    var result = db.Event.update(query, update, {upsert : false});
    if (result.nModified == 0) {
        insertSnapshotIfStartTimeStampNotExisted();         // If start_timestamp just gets modified; it's possible.
    }
}

// entry
db.Event.ensureIndex({start_timestamp:1},{unique:true});
insertSnapshotIfStartTimeStampNotExisted();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that `findAndModify` will upsert multiple events under concurrent environment. Unless your event document contains a field with an unique index, so that only one `findAndModify` successfully inserts a new event and other `findAndModify` will fail and retry with adding snapshot to the new event. For more details, see this jira ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-861

Comment: The only thing controlling whether an Event is created or not are those time constraints. There's not really a unique index I can put on it.

Comment: You can create event with a field 'last_snapshot_timestamp' to be unique, so duplicate inserts will be avoidable.

Comment: Your solution to use lock document seems to suffer the same concurrent insert issue, e.g. you can have two findAndModify reading the lock value=false at the same time. The only solution I can recommend is to use _id as your unique index, e.g, the findAndModify get the last event _id and increase it with 1, if two or more concurrent findAndModify get the same last event _id and upsert, only one will succeed.